# Is NOT IN clause supported in pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have used the In clause in PIG as

```
emp =
FILTER employee_table
BY employee_id IN ('873', '809','819','829')
;
```

Now i need to use NOT IN Clause

```
no_emp =
FILTER employee_table
BY employee_id  NOT IN ('873', '809','819','829')
;
```

which generates error as

```
2016-08-29 13:22:46,165 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 146, column 14>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'NOT'
```

Is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Boolean Operators](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/basic.html#boolops)

use only `NOT` not `NOT IN`

---

```
no_emp =
FILTER employee_table
BY employee_id  NOT ('873', '809','819','829')
;
```

if above does not work than try:
`NOT (in ('873', '809','819','829'))`

---

**Update:** `NOT IN` operator doesn't exist in `PIG`. Use `MATCHES` is Regular expression matching that Uses the Java format for regular expressions.

`BY NOT(employee_id MATCHES '8[0127][39]')`

Comment: try updated answer with `MATCHES`  - Regular expression matching

Answer (score 1):

you can use SPILT and OTHERWISE commands. an example is mentioned below

```
SPLIT employee_table INTO emp1 IF employee_id IN ('873', '809','819','829'),  emp2 OTHERWISE;
```

as you can guess, the data with 4 employee IDs will point to relation emp1 and rest will point to relation emp2